Visual Studio Connected Services and OpenAPI Controllers
I connected an OpenAPI .net core app to a .Net Framework 4.8 application by using the Connected Services / REST API Client / OpenAPI.
It properly autogenerated the code although i did not expect it would just shove every single methods in a single Client class.
1 problem is that there is more than 1 method with same name and parameter in the service but they are distinct per controllers and therefore have unique routes.
Second problem is that i have couple hundreds of controllers with on average around 7-8 methods in each but that single client just bunched those 1800+ method into one class and i expected it to either have some naming / namespace division which would fix the duplicate naming (the first problem)
Is there an option (without relying on custom command line or manual intervention) on either the client side or server side that would make the autogenerated code to be more structured.
